# Regex to capture figure after pound symbol - amounts with commas and after a space not being captured

Tags: python-3.x, regex

my code is not capturing the amount after comma in a pound amount, or if the amount comes after a space.

Here is what I have so far:

```
finalcontent=' £2,500 and also £ 1200 and also £ 7,645 and finally £8888 and london'
    
price=[]
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    import sys
    import re

    new = re.findall(r'[£]{1}\d+\.?\d{0,2}',finalcontent,re.UNICODE)

    if len(new) != 0:
    
        for prices in new:

            dumistring=str(prices)
            price.append(re.sub("[^0-9.]","",dumistring))

        for ic in range(0, len(price)): 

            price[ic] = float(price[ic]) 

        avg_cost = sum(price)/len(price)

        pricinglist.append(avg_cost)
```

output is

```
price
[2.0, 8888.0]
```

Comment: I'd strip the commas and spaces from the string before searching for numbers.

Comment: You do not need `re.UNICODE` in Python 3.x, it is ON by default. You only need it to make shorthand character classes Unicode-aware in Python 2.x. And just use `re.findall(r'£\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)',finalcontent.replace(',',''))`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/25lAU0). No need writing crazy long regexps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all commas in the string and use a much simpler pattern like

```
re.findall(r'£\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', finalcontent.replace(',',''))
# => ['2500', '1200', '7645', '8888']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/25lAU0). Note it will eliminate the need of the second regex later in the code, `re.sub("[^0-9.]","",dumistring)`.

The `£\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` pattern means:

- `£` - a pound sign
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of

    - `\.` -  a period
    - `\d+` - one or more digits

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OoXg29/1).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `re.findall` here:

```py
finalcontent = ' £2,500 and also £ 1200 and also £ 7,645 and finally £8888 and london'
pounds = re.findall(r'£\s*((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)\b', finalcontent)
print(pounds)
```

This prints:

```
['2,500', '1200', '7,645', '8888']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex used:

```regex
£                    match a Pound symbol
\s*                  followed by optional whitespace
(                    capture what follows
    (?:
        \d{1,3}      1 to 3 digits
        (?:,\d{3})*  followed by zero or more comma separated thousands groups
        |            OR
        \d+          just one or more digits (for those numbers without commas)
    )
    (?:\.\d+)?       optional decimal component
)                    stop capturing
\b                   word boundary, indicating end of Pound number term
```

Comment: I guess OP wants integers or doubles to do calculations.

Comment: Then the OP had better find out about `map(float, pounds)`

Comment: @Ray92 ... or maybe read the comment by Triplee above `:-)` ... if you want a text/regex based solution, my answer is viable.  If Python already has a library for parsing currency text into floats, then please use that first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Tripleee's comment was about converting to float